# Change Month Number to Month Name in MVVM Silverlight Application

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, silverlight-5.0

Another MVVM question

My Clip table has a field called Month.  This is a month number

I have a grid which displays the data in this table via RIA Services

Instead of showing the user month number I need to show them the name, i.e. instead of 1 show January

What is the correct approach using MVVM?

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle this via an [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) that converts the number to a name.

Comment: ok thanks where would I put the code for the IValueConverter if it would be useful in several places?

Comment: @Paul I typically have a utility project where I keep all of my view utility classes, and reference this in many of my projects.  It's really up to you, though.  This is basically part of the View layer, but very general purpose...

Comment: ok could you post me a tiny snippet?  Lets pretend we have View.XAML with a grid column Month and that the IValueConverter is in a project called SilverlightHelpers

Comment: Thanks Reed in this example the converter is implemented as part of the same namespace, I want my converter to be in its own class and namespace.  SLDashboard.Helpers I have tried to create a class called MonthNumberConverter in this folder add added    xmlns:helpers="SLDashboard2.Helpers" to the XAML but get the error the tag 'MonthNumberConverter' does not exist in XML namespace SLDashboard2.Helpers.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Paul Is it in a separate assembly?  If so, you need the xmlns to include the assembly info, as well.  Otherwise, is it public?

Comment: Fixed it thanks I should have put xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:SLDashboard2.Helpers" I missed the clr-namespace: bit

Comment: Whats the tidiest way to implement the ConvertTo in your opinion Reed?

Comment: @Paul Build a DateTime using the month, and return via DateTime.ToString formatted as you want.

Answer (score 0):

If your field is a DateTime, you can also use the Binding StringFormat: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx

That allows to specify a String format option, like short date, long date, etc...